# Nginx logging full URI with proxy_pass in the access log?

Tags: nginx, proxy

We have nginx configured with `proxy_pass` and would like to see what's the target URI after all the directive settings applied and processed. In case of error nginx has the `upstream: "https://11.22.33.44:443/test/foo-bar/"` line in the logs as below:

```
2020/03/12 02:17:37 [error] 27495#27495: *130660 connect() failed (113: No route to host) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.16.0.5, server: , request: "POST /foo-bar/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://11.22.33.44:443/test/foo-bar/", host: "test.example.com"
```

What would be the way to show the same `upstream` info in the access logs? We tried the following log config:

```
log_format main 'site="$server_name" server="$host" dest_port="$server_port" dest_ip="$server_addr" '
                'src="$remote_addr" src_ip="$realip_remote_addr" user="$remote_user" '
                'time_local="$time_local" protocol="$server_protocol" status="$status" '
                'bytes_out="$body_bytes_sent" bytes_in="$upstream_response_length" '
                'http_referer="$http_referer" http_user_agent="$http_user_agent" '
                'nginx_version="$nginx_version" http_x_forwarded_for="$http_x_forwarded_for" '
                'http_x_header="$http_x_header" uri_query="$query_string" uri_path="$uri" '
                'http_method="$request_method" response_time="$upstream_response_time" '
                'cookie="$http_cookie" request_time="$request_time" '
                'upstream_addr="$upstream_addr" upstream_http_server="$upstream_http_server"';
```

It only can show the IP address without the full path, is there any other nginx variable in the [index of variables](http://nginx.org/en/docs/varindex.html) that can show the same as error log?

Answer (score 2):

The only solution I found was having the backend store it in a response header.  Have nginx hide the header, not remove it, so you can use it in your logs.